# create dynamic url in codeigniter using .htaccess file, get data from database

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to create a dynamic URL using .htaccess file. I designed a website, its URL is:

```
localhost/social_adv/
```

I want to create a dynamic URL like below, where the `user` is dynamically fetched from the database:

```
localhost/social_adv/user
```

Here's my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^custom woddev/user [NC,L]
```

Comment: does /user directory is exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `user` is a placeholder and needs to be dynamically set. Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^social_adv/(.*)$ /woddev/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

It will match any `social_adv/USER` request (where `USER` is a placeholder) and maps it to `woddev/USER` under the hood. For example, this URL:

```
localhost/social_adv/shiva
```

Will be mapped to:

```
localhost/woddev/shiva
```

Comment: Your code is absolutely correct sir, i think my project is not supported. My controller is not execute after including your code, the error is page not found

Comment: What you get when you hit the `woddev/whatever-here` in your browser? Does the CodeIgniter app reside in `woddev/` or `social_adv`? Or both?

Comment: worked for me. This is simpler than most other answers in other pages.